# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity for OneToOne Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I am building `OneToOne` relationship between two classes  `SkuImpl` and `SkuAvailability`. below is the code for that

*SkuImpl.java*

```
@Entity 
public class SkuImpl implements  Sku {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=SkuAvailabilityImpl.class) 
    protected SkuAvailability totalSku;
    //setter and getters
}
```

*SkuAvailabilityImpl.java*

```
@Entity 
public class SkuAvailabilityImpl implements SkuAvailability{
    @OneToOne(optional=true,targetEntity=SkuImpl.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name="SKU_ID")
    protected Sku sku;
    //setter and getters
}
```

when I try to deploy application into glassfish it's not deploying, getting an exception saying

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
SkuAvailabilityImpl column: SKU_ID
(should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

how to solve this exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write `@JoinColumn` like this:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true,targetEntity=SkuImpl.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinColumn(name="SKU_ID",referencedColumnName="someNameOfColumnId")
protected Sku sku;
```

The `referencedColumnName` is the column Id in `SkuImpl` class.

The below code is unnecessary romve it:

```
  @OneToOne(targetEntity=SkuAvailabilityImpl.class) 
  protected SkuAvailability totalSku;
```

Comment: I have two table for these classes in 'SkuAvailability ' table i have fk column SKU_ID and I changed the code `name="SKU_ID",referencedColumnName="SKU_ID"`, showing same error.

Comment: I changed to this `name="SKU_AVAILABILITY_ID",referencedColumnName="SKU_ID"` now its working and deployed to glassfish thank you